# How to read different json files in python and transform into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have two json files, I was able to read the first one with this code:

```
oag_path = f"/path/file.json"
with open(oag_path, "r") as json_test:
    resp_info = json.load(json_test)
```

and then displayed it as a dataframe:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(resp_info, record_path=['data'])
df
```

and the json file looked like this:

```
{
'data': [{
'flower': 'rose',
'color': 'pink',
'season': 'spring',
'blossomTime': 'April',
'fragrance': 'fragrant',
'petals': 5,
'stemLength': 'long',
'thorns': True,
'wateringNeeds': 'moderate'
}],
'flower': 'rose',
'color': 'pink',
'season': 'spring',
'blossomTime': 'April',
'fragrance': 'fragrant',
'petals': 5,
'stemLength': 'long',
'thorns': True,
'wateringNeeds': 'moderate'
}
```

but I am unable to read the JSON file below with the code:

```
[{
'tulip': {'type': 'flower', 'color': 'red'},
'water': '',
'flower': 'sunflower',
'color': 'yellow',
'season': 'summer',
'blossomTime': 'July',
'fragrance': 'none',
'petals': 34,
'stemLength': 'tall',
'thorns': False,
'wateringNeeds': 'high'
}]
```

I get the error:

```
--> 353     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
    355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: Your second json data has fields not found in the first json data: `'tulip': {'type': 'flower', 'color': 'red'},
'water': '',`. You also explicitly tell pandas to look for the key `data`, which is absent from your second json. Your first json also has duplicate info in different formats - the all the data is in an object in a list labelled data, then _also_ in the same object that 'data' is found in

Comment: This data looks like a mess. Do you understand it, or is it new to you? Can you post more data for a fix? It looks like there are multiple irregularities that any solution must address.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that the JSON file you are trying to read is not properly formatted. Specifically, it seems that the keys in the JSON file are not enclosed in double quotes, which is required by the JSON standard.

Try replacing ' ' with " ".

Comment: try to provide a solution to the problem.